# How does one install pygobject from the official repository?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, pygtk

I want to install the Pygobject package on my Ubuntu 13.10. I tried the JHBuild option but I got stuck at the end of a very lengthy process.

The tutorial website of Pygobject says that it comes packaged with all its dependencies for nearly all Linux distros and it can be installed from the official repository of a distribution.

I looked for it on the software center but couldn't find it. All it returned it was some spellchecking libraries and development headers for gobject python bindings(I am a beginner so please let me know if this is what I need to build pygtk applications in python 3.3.2) .

I am guessing this needs to be installed using the command line interface but can't figure out how.

Comment: I suspect I hit a similar documentation issue; reported at https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/716

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Development libraries usually don't show up very well in the software center. Usually using `apt-cache search` will help here. So for example:

```
apt-cache search python gobject
```

Will show you all the packages related to python and gobject introspection. Here is a snippet of the results:

```
python-gi - Python 2.x bindings for gobject-introspection libraries
python-gi-cairo - Python Cairo bindings for the GObject library
python-gi-dbg - Python bindings for the GObject library (debug extension)
python-gi-dev - development headers for GObject Python bindings
python-gobject - Python 2.x bindings for GObject - transitional package
python-gobject-2 - deprecated static Python bindings for the GObject library
python-gobject-2-dbg - deprecated static Python bindings for the GObject library (debug extension)
python-gobject-2-dev - development headers for the static GObject Python bindings
python-gobject-dbg - Python 2.x debugging modules for GObject - transitional package
python-gobject-dev - Python 2.x development headers for GObject - transitional package
python-pyudev - Python bindings for libudev
python3-gi - Python 3 bindings for gobject-introspection libraries
python3-gi-cairo - Python 3 Cairo bindings for the GObject library
python3-gi-dbg - Python 3 bindings for gobject-introspection libraries (debug extension)
python3-pyudev - Python3 bindings for libudev
```

Since you are looking for python 3 I would install `python3-gi`, that's probably the package you are looking for, so ...

```
sudo apt-get install python3-gi
```

Comment: Yep, I have updated my answer.

Comment: You should answer with only the suggestion to install the `-gi` package, either for python 2 or python 3, as it's the preferred way to write gobject code in python, and the old pygobject bindings are deprecated. Also, you should suggest to install the `gir1.2-foo` package for any library you wish to use from python with gi.

Comment: @dobey Feel free to just edit my answer!

Comment: this solved it for me: `sudo apt install -y python-gi-dev`

Comment: `sudo -H pip3 install PyGObject`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3-gi` didn't do anything ("python3-gi is already the newest version (3.26.1-2ubuntu1)"), yet [Meld](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/meld/tree/master) still complains that it "requires pygobject 3.30.0 or higher".

Comment: @Dan, I think you need the development headers. They should be available with `sudo apt install -y python3-gi-dev`, however that package doesn't exist. Using `python-gi-dev` instead installs python 2.7 for me.

Answer (score 1):

Currently (>=python3.5) you should use `pip`. For example,

```
python -m pip install --user pygobject
```

I recommend the `--user` option to avoid permission problems and the awkward use of `sudo` (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988977/what-is-the-purpose-of-pip-install-user)).

You might get an **installation error**. In that case, it helps installing `libgirepository1.0-dev` either with the *Package Manager* or in command line with

```
sudo apt-get install libgirepository1.0-dev
```